# How can I get the source codes for the "Computer Language Benchmarks Game" (formerly known as the Great Language Shootout)?

Tags: programming-languages, benchmarking

A student and I are building a new family of interpreters, which we would like to benchmark against existing interpreters.  We would love to download a tarball or zip file containing all the source codes used in the [Computer Language Benchmarks Game](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/).  I've downloaded the zip file from the [project page](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/download/benchmarksgame-script.zip), but it contains only some infrastructure which does not work on Debian lenny, and Python source code for just 2 benchmarks.  All the other source code is MIA.

Another problem is that the interactive dropdown menu seems to show Java source no matter what language is asked for.  Not that I want to go through a zillion menus; I just want *all* the source.

I feel like a complete idiot for not being able to find this source code, but I can't.
Can anyone tell me **how can I download *all* the source code** used in the Language Benchmarks Game?

---

[NB I believe this question is in scope for SO because benchmarks are a vital resource for programmers who need to be concerned with performance.]

Comment: "does not work on Debian lenny" - That's probably a hasty conclusion (works on Ubuntu, works on Fedora, works on MS Vista). In any case, I've revised the Python script and README to give a step-by-step understanding of how to make it work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The zipball you downloaded was for the *bencher* module. You want the *bench* module (only packaged as part of the complete repo packages).

To get the benchmark sources from the official CVS:

```
cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@cvs.debian.org:/cvs/benchmarksgame login
cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@cvs.debian.org:/cvs/benchmarksgame checkout benchmarksgame/bench
```

The repo is also available as an [unofficial mirror on Github](http://github.com/kragen/shootout):

```
git clone git://github.com/kragen/shootout.git
```

Official repo tarball: https://alioth.debian.org/snapshots.php?group_id=100815

Unofficial mirror repo zipball: https://github.com/kragen/shootout/zipball/master

(see http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/play.php#misc)

Comment: Brilliant!  All sources I tried were useful.  How did you figure this out??

Comment: From the last link: "You can grab the source code for all the programs (or just some of the programs) from [the project CVS repository](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/?group_id=30402) - **co shootout/bench** (There's also [an independent GitHub clone](https://github.com/kragen/shootout) of the project CVS repository.)"

Comment: Is there a more up to date way to get it now that the project has moved in Alioth to benchmarksgame rather than shootout? Currently the only method I can get to work is via the GitHub clone.

Comment: Looks like whatever was causing the issue earlier today has been solved- I've updated the URLs from [here](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/?group_id=100815).

Comment: >>Official repo tarball<< Not since Dec 2012. Please update your answer to group_id=100815 and http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/play.php

Comment: >>Official repo tarball<< Has no updates since 08/2014 so please remove that link. The benchmarks game website provides a zip of the source code: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/download/benchmarksgame-sourcecode.zip

Comment: >>Unofficial mirror repo zipball<< Has no updates since 2011 so please remove that link.

Comment: I have added a new mirror, which might be useful to some: https://github.com/Byron/benchmarksgame-cvs-mirror

Answer (score 3):

From the [GitLab archive](https://salsa.debian.org/benchmarksgame-team/archive-alioth-benchmarksgame).

From the current [source-code zip-file](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/download/benchmarksgame-sourcecode.zip).