# How to get jruby benchmark tests and frameworks for "Compute Language Benchmark Game"

Tags: java, programming-languages, jruby, performance-testing, microbenchmark

I built a Java package for JDK and the API aims to improve the some dynamic type language interpreters, e.g., JRuby. I want to have the general performance improvement by this package. Therefore, some benchmark tests are important.

I google the and find there is one benchbark: [Computer Language Benchmark Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/). From the webpage, there are some performance comparision for the JRuby vs Ruby. But when i searched the benchmark tests, nothing JRuby test cases are found. There is only test frameworks (no JRuby test): https://github.com/kragen/shootout and [Benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157153/how-can-i-get-the-source-codes-for-the-computer-language-benchmarks-game-form)

Anyone can provide information how to get ALl source code (both bencher framework and JRuby tests cases)? Thanks /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[all source code](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/download/benchmarksgame-sourcecode.zip)

[bencher framework](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/download/benchmarksgame-script.zip)